# Login System with a DB Connection Class don't login. Return with else error for invalid login

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm new with DB classes and working on it. I'm trying to make my old login system work with this DB class but it returns with my else for invalid login error, like there is no such e-mail and password in the DB. But there is.

Connection Class:

```
class Conexao
{
private $link;

public function __construct($host = null, $username = null, $password = null, $dbName = null)
{
$this->link = mysqli_init();
$this->link->real_connect($host, $username, $password, $dbName) or die("Failed to connect");
}

public function __destruct()
{
$this->link->close();
}

public function Query($sql)
{
return $this->link->query($sql);
}
```

Login Page:

```
<?php
include('dbConnect.php');
session_start();

$conexao = new Conexao("localhost", "root", "XXXXX", "festas");

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexao,$_POST['email']);

$pass = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexao,$_POST['senha']);

$sel_user = $conexao->Query("SELECT * from contas where email='$email' AND senha='$pass'");

$check_user = mysqli_num_rows($sel_user);

$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sel_user);

if($check_user>0){

$_SESSION['user_email']=$email;

header('Location: ../adminpage.php');

mysqli_free_result($result);
} else {
header('Location: ../admin.php?erroLogin=1');
}

}

?>
```

Always it returns with the "else" header('Location: ../admin.php?erroLogin=1'). I think it could be because of "$check_user = mysqli_num_rows($sel_user);" but I tried to fix and can't. Tried also "$conexao->num_rows($sel_user).

Comment: quite a few things are unknown and you need to see if your POST arrays are not empty and rendering values correctly. Then, make sure the column types are correct and are long enough for the password. Check for possible errors with error reporting and MySQL error checking.

Comment: Hi. Yes, everything is OK with form and DB. How can I check his errors reportings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. Here's what I did:

In DB class php:

```
public function Escape($sql)
{
    return $this->link->real_escape_string($sql);
}
```

then in login php:

```
$email = $conexao->Escape($_POST['email']);
```

Thanks!